# Emacs clojure repl does not show any errors or exceptions

Tags: logging, emacs, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I am using emacs for clojure development. I use `M-X cider-jack-in` for repl.

When i ran my jetty server with one handler for file-upload, i saw that file-upload was not working.
But repl was not showing any `pprint` logs.

I switched to console and did `lein repl`.
After i did the workflow again, i saw the request logs and exception.

I wasted a lot of time in thinking what was going wrong.

can we enable that logging would be directed to repl ?

Comment: Which CIDER version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the buffer `*nrepl-server*` to see the full output. It's not visible by default in the buffer list though it will likely have what you are looking for.

<kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd> b *nrepl-server <kbd>tab</kbd> will cycle through the output buffers for your various cider sessions.

In practice mapping the output to the repl for all threads makes using the REPL really hard because I can't type without being interrupted.

Comment: You say "by default' -- is there a way to change that behavior? It's sometimes useful to include logging in the REPL output.